# UHF band repeater

Tags: signal, antenna, transmitter, tv

I want to make a device which gets the TV antenna signals and transmits it again.  Is there any module available in market which simplifies construction or i should make from scratch? Since my background is in software, please explain simple.

Comment: Transmit at same frequency or a different frequency and, what power output?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because such a device is illegal.

Comment: @LeonHeller I can't see any correlation between on-topicness and legality.

Comment: Encouraging an illegal act is generally illegal.

Comment: @LeonHeller nothing encouraging about answering this question. Still, legality != on-topicness. Also, pretty sure that answering a question is covered by free speech, and also, not anyone's job to censor knowledge of how things can be done, and also, what's illegal encouragement is subject to individual *jurisdiction*; and as far as I can tell, neither of us is a judge,

Comment: He says he wants to make such a device.

Comment: and I say I'm not encouraging him if I explain why that's hard. Seriously, don't self-censor engineers.

Comment: Also note that it's only illegal for where *you* or *I* are, @LeonHeller, and not for OP, per se, and even so only iff ehsan decides to forward that TV on a licensed band. If he builds a local legislature-compatible transverter, I don't see the slightest legal problem. I don't know OP's legislation, and neither do you. I'm not a fan of people crowding spectrum, but this is a legit question and shouldn't be closed just because you feel it *might* or *should* be illegal *where you are*.

Comment: @LeonHeller: Such a device is not illegal in most jurisdictions, but it would need to be licensed. Indeed, they are quite common in mountainous rural areas where receiving signals directly is impossible.

Comment: @LeonHeller Given the OP's likely location the assessment ion of 'legaility' **may** need to include the validity and actions of the state. Are you an unquestioning  supporter of all oppressive regimes or do you feel that local circumstances MAY have some relevance. Or may not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe definitely contains an amplifier; small-amplitude signals go in, high-amplitude signals go out.

Now for problems:

- If you're on the same frequency as the received signal, your amplified signal will interfere with the received, weak signal. Hence, same-frequency forwarding can only work if the "end receiver" only gets one of the two signals, not a combination of both. For cable TV, that is the case, so that's why you can get very cheap UHF amplifiers. For antenna TV, that's not the case, so you can't have same frequency relaying.
- If you need to change the frequency while relaying, you need what is often called a *transverter*: The received signal is pre-amplified, mixed with a single tone that shifts everything in frequency, and transmitted through a power amplifier. This is significantly more complex.

In either case, you'll need proper input and output filters (which will be very complex, considering the TV spectrum isn't necessarily one continuous block) and you will be operating illegally, with a device that, per definition of what it does, is easy to find. I don't know where you live, but I don't think there's any place on earth I'd do this.

Regarding the question of building such a device yourself:

Well, it's certainly not a starter project for electronics beginners; TV signals, even the ones that "look bad on screen" are sent with relatively high power by the "official" TV towers, compared to the powers that e.g. are in the cell phone signals that reach your telephone. So this will  be a challenge in amplification, testing, power supply, filtering, mixing, tone generation and general RF design, which is a discipline on its own.

Comment: The idea of making such device is in my home the Tv should be near the antenna plug that limits me for proper tv place. I wanted this device to connect to antenna plug and the other receiver to the TV _Av in_ port

Comment: um, use a longer cable?

Comment: It is neater solution to be cable-less!

Comment: no, in this situation, I'd disagree.

Comment: If you're just trying to distribute TV within your house, there are commercial products designed specifically to do this.